# Failed to resolve: use of undeclared crate or module `sp_io` in Substrate Kitties Chain

Tags: kitties, substrate-kitties-chain

While building the Substrate Kitties Chain using the tutorial: https://docs.substrate.io/tutorials/v3/kitties/pt1/

I got the error like :

`PS C:\Users\msi\kitties-tutorial> cargo build --release
warning: C:\Users\msi\kitties-tutorial\pallets\kitties\Cargo.toml: unused manifest key: dependencies.serde.feature
warning: Git command failed with status: exit code: 128
warning: Could not find .git/HEAD searching from C:\Users\msi\kitties-tutorial\node upwards!
Compiling node-kitties-runtime v4.0.0-dev (C:\Users\msi\kitties-tutorial\runtime)
Compiling pallet-kitties v4.0.0-dev (C:\Users\msi\kitties-tutorial\pallets\kitties)
error[E0433]: failed to resolve: use of undeclared crate or module sp_io

--> pallets\kitties\src\lib.rs:4:5
|
4 | use sp_io::hashing::blake2_128;
|     ^^^^^ use of undeclared crate or module sp_io`

error[E0425]: cannot find value `blake2_128` in this scope
--> pallets\kitties\src\lib.rs:135:26
|
135 |             payload.using_encoded(blake2_128)
|                                   ^^^^^^^^^^ help: a unit struct with a similar name exists: `Blake2_128`
|
::: C:\Users\msi.cargo\git\checkouts\substrate-7e08433d4c370a21\22d40c7\frame\support\src\hash.rs:143:1
|
143 | pub struct Blake2_128;
| ---------------------- similarly named unit struct `Blake2_128` defined here

warning: unused import: `scale_info::TypeInfo`
--> pallets\kitties\src\lib.rs:2:5
|
2 | use scale_info::TypeInfo;
|     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
|
= note: `#[warn(unused_imports)]` on by default

I have added sp-io crates in pallets\kitties\cargo.toml in [dev-dependincies] as

`sp-io = { default-features = false, version = "5.0.0", git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", branch = "polkadot-v0.9.17" }`

and in ["std"] as
`std = [
"codec/std",
"scale-info/std",
"frame-support/std",
"frame-system/std",
"frame-benchmarking/std",
"sp-io/std",
]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you have declare sp-io in [dev-dependencies] if this is true then please moved sp-io from [dev-dependencies] to [dependencies].

Comment: This is probably the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

It seems sp-io is using the v5, whereas the other crates are using v4. try using the v4 of sp-io :

```
[dependecies]
sp-io = { default-features = false, git = 'https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git', tag = 'devhub/latest', version = '4.0.0-dev' }
```

Comment: It starts to give a cargo error: Execution failed (exit code 101).
C:/Users/msi/.cargo/bin/cargo.exe metadata --verbose --format-version 1 --all-features
stdout :     Updating git repository `https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git`
error: failed to select a version for the requirement `sp-io = "^4.0.0-dev"`
candidate versions found which didn't match: 5.0.0
location searched: Git repository https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git?tag=devhub/latest
required by package `pallet-kitties v4.0.0-dev (C:\Users\msi\kitties-tutorial\pallets\kitties)`

stderr :